# Proper components usage in ST2 application

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, architecture, sencha-touch-2

I have a quite simple mobile app I want to build with Sencha Touch 2. I have quite a lot of experience with ExtJs, but not really with their MVC architecture. What I want to achieve is :

- first a main screen with toolbar and some icons rendered in the middle which are to be used to navigate across the app functionality.
- clicking one of the icons should switch to a screen with a scrollable list.

What I'm struggling with is the proper place to define the views, and controllers. As well as should for example the main screen use a controller ? Should I create a viewport manually or not ?

What I have right now, which is not rendering anything apart of the toolbar :

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'SG',

    views: [
        'Main',
        'MainScreen'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SG.view.Main'));
    }
})
```

Main.js

```
Ext.define('SG.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'ShopGun.view.MainScreen'
    ],
    config: {
        layout : 'fit',

        items: [
            {
                title: 'Welcome',
                iconCls: 'home',
                position: 'top',
                scrollable: true,

                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'SG Alpha 1'
                    }
                    Ext.create('SG.view.MainScreen', {
                        docked: 'bottom'
                    })
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

MainScreen.js

```
Ext.define('SG.view.MainScreen', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mainScreen',

    initialize : function(){

        Ext.define("MenuIcon", {
            extend: "Ext.data.Model",
            config: {
                fields: [
                    {name: "Name", type: "string"},
                    {name: "Icon",  type: "string"}
                ]
            }
        });

        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'MenuIcon',
            data: [
                {
                    Name: "A",
                    Icon: "a.png"
                },
                {
                    Name: "B",
                    Icon: "b.png"
                }
            ]
        });

        this.html = 'foo';

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And finally an image of what I'd like to get :

[image]

---

EDIT:

A senchafiddle demo here : http://www.senchafiddle.com/#jSqtV (which is not rendering at all but doesn't throw any errors).

Comment: put a comma between your items in main view, title bar and your mainscreen view

Comment: see console for what error you are getting

Comment: I'm not getting any error. And the comma missing is just a typo when copying.

Comment: can u host it on to sencha fiddle?